# Xcode 5. Tab bar controller without title - only icons

Tags: ios7, tabbar, tabbarcontroller

i have a tab bar controller and i want to remove the title and leave only icons (images). Thanks for the help.

Examples:

http://a1.mzstatic.com/eu/r30/Purple4/v4/ef/b4/3a/efb43a0c-c955-b7f8-9c1a-01a5a6492ba6/screen568x568.jpeg

http://a3.mzstatic.com/eu/r30/Purple4/v4/3b/7e/f0/3b7ef083-6fac-3ae1-d3df-87b52ce91158/screen568x568.jpeg

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, how I can remove the property title and just leave the icons on a tab bar item? as instagram, tumblr and mega.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just don't give title to tab bar item. make it blank in property title or don't set title by code. By this it will not show the title to tab bar item and only icon will be shown.

Comment: I did that, but the icon doesn't fill the entire space of the tab bar item...
https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/167x435q90/r/843/uo6d.png
as if the property title even existed